# How can I exclude a class inside a regex string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to build a regex which replaces all HTML tags inside a string, excluding a special element. The problem is that I've found no way excluding the closing tag of the special element also. This is my code:

```js
let str = 'You have to pay <div class="keep-this">$200</div> per <span class="date">month</span> for your <span class="vehicle">car</span> <div class="keep-this">$500</div> also';

console.log(str.replace(/(?!<div class="keep-this">)(<\/?[^>]+(>|$))/g, ""));
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Would it be an option to use something else than regex?

Comment: Yes, the main thing is that the purpose is achieved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this option, which matches all HTML tags, excluding those tags which have the attribute `class="keep-this"`.

```js
let str = 'You have to pay <input class="some-class"/> blah <div class="keep-this">$200</div> per <span class="date">month</span> for your <span class="vehicle">car</span> <div class="keep-this">$500</div> also';

console.log(str.replace(/<\s*([^\s>]+)(?:(?!\bclass="keep-this")[^>])*>(.*?)(?:<\/\1>)|<\s*([^\s>]+)(?:(?!\bclass="keep-this")[^>])*\/>/g, "$2"));
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
<                                 match < of an opening tag
\s*                               optional whitespace
([^\s>]+)                         match and capture the HTML tag name in $1 (\1)
(?:(?!\bclass="keep-this")[^>])*  match remainder of tag,
                                  so long as class="keep-this" is not seen
>                                 match > of an opening tag
(.*?)                             match and capture the tag's content in $2,
                                  until hitting the nearest
(?:<\/\1>)                        closing tag, which matches the opening one
|                                 OR
<\s*([^\s>]+)                     match a standalone tag e.g. <input/>
(?:(?!\bclass="keep-this")[^>])*  without a closing tag
\/>                               which matches
```

Then, we simply replace all such matches with empty string, to effectively remove them.

Comment: Nice! There's a missing closing bracket on the 4th line of the explanation though.

Comment: No...check line #6...the closing bracket is there

Comment: Ah, I meant `)` instead of `>`. It's missing, right?

Comment: You should add `s` flag in case a tag to be removed spans across multiple lines.or else use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the explanation. But now the text between the HTML tags is gone I thing. This must be kept.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Sorry, I guess I missed that requirement.  My answer only needed a small change.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No problem! You have my full respect. Regex is some hard stuff.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Just found out that for example `<input class="some-class">` is a problem (No closing tag elements). Maybe is there a way to exclude them also?

Comment: @Mr.Jo Just make the closing tag optional, see the updated answer.

Comment: When I click `Run code snippet`, I can see no closing tag `</div>`

Comment: I fixed it.  The problem is that a valid empty HTML tag must look like `<input />`, that is, is must end with `/>`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now it seems to be perfect. I'm currently implementing this. If everything looks good after testing, I'll checkmark your answer with gratitude!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all the html elements that do not have the class `keep-this` you might also make use of [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and for example use [:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not).

```js
let str = 'You have to pay <div class="keep-this">$200</div> per <span class="date">month</span> for your <span class="vehicle">car</span> <div class="keep-this">$500</div> also';
let parser = new DOMParser();
let doc = parser.parseFromString(str, "text/html");
doc.querySelectorAll("body *:not(.keep-this)").forEach(e => e.replaceWith(e.innerHTML));
console.log(doc.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Here the word `month` and `car` is removed.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Ah I see :)  I removed the element. I have updated it replacing it with the innerHTML.